# Disallow entity declarations but allow DTDs

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I am given an XML document that must be allowed to have a Document Type Declaration (DTD), but we prohibit any ENTITY declarations.

The XML document is parsed with `SAXParser.parse()`, as follows:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
factory.setValidating(true);

SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
```

The XML is then passed into the parser as an `InputSource`:

```
InputSource inputSource= ... ;
parser.parse(inputSource, handler);
```

And the `handler` has a `resolveEntity` method, which `SAXParser.parse()` calls:

```
public InputSource resolveEntity(String pubID, String sysID) throws SAXException {
  InputSource inputSource = null;
  try {
     inputSource = entityResolver.resolveEntity(publicId, systemId);
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
     throw new SAXException(e);
  }
  return inputSource;
}
```

When I pass in an XML file with an ENTITY reference, it seems that nothing is being done - no exceptions are thrown and nothing is stripped - to or about the prohibited ENTITY reference.

Here is an example of the bad XML I am using. The DTD should be allowed, but the !ENTITY line should be disallowed:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "foo.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY gotcha SYSTEM "file:///gotcha.txt"> <!-- This is disallowed-->
]>

<label>&gotcha;</label>
```

What do I need to do to make sure that ENTITY references are disallowed in the XML, but that DTDs are still allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `org.xml.sax.ext.DeclHandler` on the SaxParser.

```
parser.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", myDeclHandler);
```

The DeclHandler gets notified when a internal entity declaration is parsed. To disallow entity decls you can simple throw a SAXException:

```
public class MyDeclHandler extends org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2 {
     public void internalEntityDecl(String name, String value) throws SAXException {
         throw new SAXException("not allowed");
     }
}
```